# How do I add 2 types of sets?

Tags: python

for example

```
a = set()
b = set()
a.add(10)
b.add(5)

a = a + b #(This will error)
```

The goal I want is a = {5,10}. Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding two sets is the same as getting the union of `a` and `b`:

```
>>> a = set()
>>> b = set()
>>> a.add(10)
>>> b.add(5)
>>> a.union(b)
set([10, 5])
```

Remember that sets don't have duplicate items, so the union of `{5, 10}` and `{5}` will result in `{5, 10}`.

Another way you can do this syntax-wise is using the pipe operator:

```
>>> a|b
set([10, 5])
```